# Poweredge 2650 is it 64 bit capable?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I'm trying to figure out whether a poweredge 2650 server is 64 bit capable? It has 2xIntel xeon processors @ 3.2ghz L2:512kb L3:1MB I believe manufactured sometime in 2004.

cat /proc/cpuinfo

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 2
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.20GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 3185.617
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 2
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe pebs bts cid xtpr
bogomips    : 6371.23
clflush size    : 64
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 2
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.20GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 3185.617
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 3
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 2
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe pebs bts cid xtpr
bogomips    : 6371.08
clflush size    : 64
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 2
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.20GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 3185.617
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 2
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe pebs bts cid xtpr
bogomips    : 6370.75
clflush size    : 64
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 2
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.20GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 3185.617
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 3
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 2
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe pebs bts cid xtpr
bogomips    : 6370.77
clflush size    : 64
```

sudo dmidecode --type processor

```
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.3 present.

Handle 0x0400, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: Proc_1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Xeon
    Manufacturer: Intel
    ID: 25 0F 00 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 15, Model 2, Stepping 5
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (Fast floating-point save and restore)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Hyper-threading technology)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Not Specified
    Voltage: 1.5 V
    External Clock: 533 MHz
    Max Speed: 3200 MHz
    Current Speed: 3200 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: ZIF Socket
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0700
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0701
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0702
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified

Handle 0x0401, DMI type 4, 35 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: Proc_2
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Xeon
    Manufacturer: Intel
    ID: 25 0F 00 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 15, Model 2, Stepping 5
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (Fast floating-point save and restore)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Hyper-threading technology)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Not Specified
    Voltage: 1.5 V
    External Clock: 533 MHz
    Max Speed: 3200 MHz
    Current Speed: 3200 MHz
    Status: Populated, Idle
    Upgrade: ZIF Socket
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0703
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0704
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0705
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It **lacks the `lm` flag** (*Long Mode*), so the answer is **no, it is not 64 bit capable**.

An example reference could be found at [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-find-if-processor-is-64-bit-or-not/).

Answer (score 4):

No, your CPU does not support EM64T, and your motherboard does not support EM64T-capable CPUs, either, according to [Intel's FAQ](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/xeon/sb/CS-012580.htm):

> Q. Will my current 533 MHz FSB systems
>   (e.g. SE7501WV2) support Intel
>   processors with Intel Extended Memory
>   64 Technology?
>
> A. No.

This suggests that EM64T is only available on 800MHz FSB and faster CPUs.  Furthermore, your motherboard would not support EM64T CPUs, based on your motherboard's 533 MHz FSB listed in the [PowerEdge 2650](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dell.com%2Fdownloads%2Fglobal%2Fproducts%2Fpedge%2Fen%2F2650_specs.pdf&ei=qyTWSrDPDpPgMa_jsJUD&usg=AFQjCNE8UqOCnhe7CPjhV3nfRYlKjlDs7w&sig2=VFd3PBctfNn_kl1piIy7LQ) specs.

An easy test to confirm this on any system would be to download a 64-bit Linux live CD and try to boot off the CD.

Your particular CPU is probably one of these, based on the specs:

http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SL72Y

http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SL73Q